# Login pop-up for Home page module links

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

I have to display a login-pop-up window when the user clicks on the links in a custom module. I have the pop-up using rokbox and am displaying it for other links. I am adding the links to the module from adminside and it the user is not logged in it should show the link for rokbox pop-up and if he is logged it should show the actual link. Please let me know where I need to make modifications. I think I can get all the module contents inside the default.php of mod_custom and can check the conditions. But then also , it will be applied for all the custom modules. Now how can I specify it is checking the condition for a particular module in Home page.

It will be helpful if someone can answer it ASAP.

Comment: What do you want exactly and what do you have done?

Comment: What version of Joomla? A custom module or the custom HTML module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Joomla 1.5 and a custom module so you can execute what ever code you want -

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if($user->id)
{
    //show logged in link
}
else
{
    //show link to login form
}
```

If you are using the Custom HTML module then you will need to add an extension that allows you to include PHP code in the content or you will need to code a custom module to display the links.

Comment: Actually I think I know it :) but in that case the one who adds content has to write all the PHP code. I was looking for a method that will help do it without adding individual codes.But as of now nothing seems to be working and I am going to use your method.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using Extension called Jumi. This will allow us to insert/call custom PHP code. What I did is, I put the contents in a PHP file and called it in a article. So in the PHP file we can check whether the user is logged in and other things. Then I called this article in a module.Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand your question, but here is my solution if i understand you correctly:

on the head of every page add:

```
<?php if (isset ($_GET['msg'])) {
    $message = $_GET['msg']; ?>
    <script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
    alert (<?php $message ?>);
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

and then whenever you want to have a custom message popup on the next page add ?msg="Welcome user" to the url in your link.